# How to list packages that depend on a certain version of a dependency?

Tags: debian, package-management, ffmpeg, dependencies

I heard that maybe upgrading to a newer version of FFMPEG than what's included in Debian by default might solve some of my problems. But I've had [bad experiences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52617527/6743127) with upgrading packages like that, sometimes packages depend on explicitly an older version of another package.

I can run `apt-cache rdepends ffmpeg` to see which programs depend on FFMPEG in general, but that doesn't tell me which ones might break when I upgrade it.

How can I see which packages depend on this specific version of FFMPEG? Is this even saved anywhere or just a complex property of each program?

<sub>Bonus: If upgrading messes something up, can I go back?</sub>

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but maybe a helpful commend nontheless: I have multiple versions of `ffmpeg` on my system. The distribution-supplied version is installed globally via package-manager. Other versions (some built by myself) reside in `/opt` and I explicitly request preferring them by setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: That sounds helpful indeed (and very similar to the solution I used for the Dolphin emulator). How would I install FFMPEG in such a way?

Comment: When building the `ffmpeg` version of your choice (I assume any version available from github), configure with `--prefix=/opt/ffmpeg/$(cat RELEASE) --disable-shared --enable-static --extra-cflags=--static --extra-libs="-ldl"`. You can look at complete examples at [my blog](https://ssl.hehoe.de/artikel/blog/ffmpeg-fur-avxsynth-oder-ultrastar-deluxe-kompilieren.html) (the full command does not fit into a comment). Adjust as needed.

Comment: Install your build by any method you like. I prefer `checkinstall`: `sudo checkinstall --pkgname="ffmpeg-$(cat RELEASE)" --pkgversion="$(cat RELEASE)~git$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)" --backup=no --deldoc=yes --fstrans=no --default`

Comment: Then launch your application with a modified library search path: `env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ffmpeg-x.y/lib yourapplication`. You can also `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ffmpeg-x.y/lib`  and then launch your application from the same shell session.

Comment: In case you want to develop against your custom install using `pkgconfig`, set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/ffmpeg-x.y/lib/pkconfig` in your build environment.

Comment: What I figured out since I asked this question: The encoder is also overloaded when I'm just recording and another program is taking up some considerable amount of resources (my test case was Minecraft 1.12.2 with low render distance, which normally shouldn't cause a big problem). So I followed your instructions (and improvised a bit whenever they didn't work or my setup was different) and ran OBS with FFMPEG 4.1.4. I wasn't able to verify the FFMPEG version inside OBS, so I must trust that your "env" command works. The result: Still overloaded in 1080p when Minecraft is running, even 50 Kbps.

Comment: No need for trust. You can use `env LD_DEBUG=files LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ffmpeg-x.y/lib yourapplication`. The loader will print the paths of the loaded shared object files so you can verify the desired ones are loaded.

Comment: By "overloaded" you mean "ambiguous implementations" or "poor results due to A) lack of bandwidth or B) lack of processing power".

Comment: Assuming your new version is also a deb, what happens if you run `apt-get -s install your-ffmpeg.deb`? That should tell you if anything is bad enough to break things on the package level without actually applying any changes. Also, @Hermann mentioned using `checkinstall`, but didn't mention that using it gives you the option to undo any changes it makes.

Comment: @Joe How do I find out what `-s` does? `apt-get --help` doesn't tell me anything about the options that it has, other than that there are some. Instead it directs me towards "`apt-get(8)`", which is not a valid command.

Comment: `man apt-get` `-s, --simulate, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon, --no-act` - the rest is too long for a comment

Comment: @Joe What? What is that command supposed to do and what do you mean with the "rest"?

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit too terse. In a terminal window, type `man apt-get`. The `man` command shows you the manual page for any command which has one (most do). Specifying the `-s` flag on the `apt-get` command  (or  any of the synonyms listed above) will cause it to simulate whatever the rest of the command parameters tell it to do (e.g. install your variant deb) without actually changing anything on your system. If this would cause other packages to be uninstalled or upgraded to new versions, this should tell you that without actually doing it.

Comment: Manual pages are designed to remind you of what the parameters and options for a command are. They are very useful and occasionally even have some examples. I say "remind", because they are usually not designed to teach you how to use the command. For that, you need, books, articles, classes, or tutorials found elsewhere. They are meant to be a quick, definitive reference.

Comment: The reference to `apt-get(8)` tells you that the information you want is on the apt-get man page which is in section 8 of the manual system which is devoted to system administration commands. Since apt-get is only in section 8, that part doesn't matter here. Some commands are in more than one section and if you don't want the first one man finds, you have to tell it what section to look in. The command, `man man` shows you the manual page for man itself.